# Build Error using React CRA RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (Terser)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm stuck with this error for a long time and I tried every post talking about `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

I'm using a React CRA app, and I suddenly have this error when I try to build the project :

```
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the bundle. Error: static/js/5.d8dbe471.chunk.js from Terser
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\build.js:188:23
    at finalCallback (C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:257:39)
    at C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:273:13
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at onCompiled (C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:271:21)
    at C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:681:15
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:678:31
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1423:35
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1414:32
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\aaa\playground\web\payback_reactjs\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Read more here: https://cra.link/failed-to-minify

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@3.2.1 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@3.2.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-22T09_22_26_405Z-debug.log
```

Node version : v12.21.0
NPM version : 6.14.11

Terser version in `package.json` is `"terser": "^5.14.2"`

I've tried to removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, also tried using Yarn with no success, and I also tried `set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`

I reverted to my old commits when the build was working, still the same error.